# Loop Trough CSV for start_request

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Python and tried to loop through a CSV file with two columns; name and ZIP-code:

```
Name of Company, 1234
```

The final URL should look like that:

```
https://www.example.com/result.aspx?what=Name+of+Comapny&where=1234
```

I tried it this way:

> class csvSpider(scrapy.Spider):
>       name = 'csv_spider'
>
> ```
> def start_requests(self):
>     with open('test.csv') as f:
>         for line in f:
>             if not line.strip():
>                 continue
>             print 'https://www.example.com/result.aspx?what=' + line[0] + '&where=' + line[1]   
>             yield Request('https://www.example.com/result.aspx?what=' + line[0] + '&where=' + line[1])
> ```

I also imported the CSV module at the beginning of the Python file.

Not sure what I am doing wrong - how can I make that work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why have you used yield? Though it is right but is it correct logic?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html